# Setting axis limits / zooming in in a ggdist plot (stat_slab) - coord_cartesian fails

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot predicted draws from a brms model using ggdist, specifically stat_slab, and having issues with coord_cartesian to zoom in. Coord_cartesian succeeds in cropping the x-axis on the lower end, i.e. ggdist object is displayed correctly if adjusting xlim low value from 0 to 50. However, when limiting xlim at the upper end (e.g. 2000 to 1000) slab fill disappears from those stat_slabs whose tails go beyond the upper xlim value. It seems that coord_cartesian fails at the upper end at the distribution. Here's a code that should show what happens:

```
theme_set(theme_tidybayes() + panel_border())

set.seed(1)
vars = data.frame(year = rep(c("before","after"), each = 1100),
           treatment = rep(c("low","high","low","high"), each = 550))
dat = data.frame(vars, .value = rgamma(nrow(vars),
                                                    scale = 100, shape = 4))
ggplot(dat, 
       aes(x = .value, y = treatment, group= year, fill=year, color = year)) +
  stat_slab(alpha=0.6, slab_color = "black") + 
  #coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 2000)) +  # all values
  #coord_cartesian(xlim = c(300, 2000)) +  # success at lower end
  #coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1000))  + # fill disappears in one slab
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 900)) -> reprex1 # fill disappears in 3 slabs
```

[plot that I get when running the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9DqF.png)
In addition, in my actual plots I would like to use slab_color=NA, and use only fill and manual fill color scales - so it's really unfortunate that the fill disappears... I really haven't found a solution, so thank you if someone can help.

EDIT: The problem seems to be somehow associated with R graphics and plotting window size. The smaller the window or plotting area, the more fills appear in the slabs, I think. Two examples with different sizes:

```
reprex1
tiff(paste0(getwd(),"/reprex1.tiff"), 
     res=600, compression="lzw",
     height = 9, width = 13, units = "in")
print(reprex1)
dev.off()
```

[all fills disappear when plot size is large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJuK9.png),

```
reprex1
tiff(paste0(getwd(),"/reprex1.tiff"), 
     res=600, compression="lzw",
     height = 3, width = 5, units = "in")
print(reprex1)
dev.off()
```

[while in the smaller sized plot already two slabs are filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar8bM.png). What could cause this?

I'm using R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18), ggdist 2.4.1 and ggplot2 3.3.5. All packages are up to date. I have the problem both in base R and RStudio.

BR,
Maria

[Short rationale for why I want to zoom in: My data has a lot of variation, and the tails of the slabs are massive, making it difficult to see the differences in year*treatment means. Therefore, I want to zoom in the plot a bit to focus on the high-density area]

Comment: Have you tried on the latest versions of both packages (e.g. after `update.packages(ask = FALSE)`)? I tried quickly on ggdist 2.4.0 and 2.4.1 and it worked as expected (no missing slabs). Mind you I am on ggplot2 3.3.5; not sure if anything has changed there...

Comment: Hi Matthew, and thanks for the reply and tip - oh I should have made sure to update them! However, this is weird - I updated ggplot2 (3.3.5) and ggdist (2.4.1) [and all other packages], but the problem persists - the first two coord_cartesian options work fine, the latter two drop slab fills. I'm completely clueless.

Comment: EDITED the original question to include a link to my plot as well as the updated package version info.

Comment: It seems the issue is related to the R graphics device and plotting window size. When changing the size of R graphics window in base R (tried that too, normally in RStudio), the slab fills emerged and disappeard again. Also, when saving the plot using tiff(res=600, compression="lzw"), different height (2 vs. 5 inches) and width (4 vs. 7 inches) settings result in plots with different slabs filled - as the plot code remains the same. The smaller the plot size, the more slabs appear with fills. When increasing the tiff() dimensions to e.g. 9x13, all fills disappear from the saved plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah okay, I have no idea *why*, but I think this is related to `alpha` values on the Windows graphics device (which it looks like you are using).

If I run your code on the Cairo graphics device, I get the expected output:

[image: densities on Cairo device do not disappear]

But if I run it on the Windows graphics device, I get this:

[image: densities on Windows device disappear]

If I remove `alpha=0.6` from the call to `stat_slab()`, the densities come back:

[image: densities on Windows without alpha do not disappear]

I'm not sure what's going on, but it appears to be some interaction between alpha fills and clipping on the Windows graphics device in R. I'm not sure there's a fix at the ggdist level.

My main suggestion would be to switch to using the Cairo graphics device, which produces nicer-looking plots anyway (the antialiasing on plots generated on the Windows graphics device is quite ugly --- notice the jagged lines in its plots and the smooth lines in the Cairo plots).

If you are using RStudio 1.4+ you can change to the Cairo device by default in the Settings panel:

[image: Rstudio Options -> General -> Graphics -> Graphics Device]

And if you are saving files as PNGs you can pass `type = "cairo"` to the `png()` function.

Comment: Dear Matthew, thank you so much! Yes, that solved it for me - would never have figured this out on my own. Thanks also for the tip on using Cairo in general!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! R graphics is often... weird :/.

Comment: I was having the same issue and this is the only post I could find that actually helped, Thank you!!